# Post liked a user in RecyclerView firestore

Tags: android, firebase, collections, google-cloud-firestore

> I want to display post in recyclerView along with it's like count(**unique user like this post**)

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- users (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- uid (documents)
   |          |
   |          --- name: "User Name"
   |          |
   |          --- email: "email@email.com"
   |          |
   |          --- userID: uid
   |
   --- posts (collection)
   |      |
   |     --- postid (documents)
   |          |
   |          --- title: "User Name"
   |          |
   |          --- description: "postDetail"
   |          |
   |          --- postID: postid
   |          |
   |          --- likeCount: 24  -> by unique users
   |
   --- likes (collection)
   |      |
   |     --- likeid (documents) -> userID + postID
   |          |
   |          --- userID: true
   |          |
   |          --- postID: true
```

I know I can check for each question whether it's like by current user using

```
db.collection("likes").doc(userID + questionID).get().{ doc ->
  if(doc.exists){ 
    //if this is successful it means this user has liked the question.
  }
}
```

**I have to call this for all items in recyclerView . Is there any better or easy way ?**

Comment: If you think that you can have a reasonable number of likes per post, then check **[this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57231519/get-information-if-the-feed-is-liked-by-the-user-in-a-single-query-firestore)** out.

Comment: @AlexMamo I think I have numerous number of like . I have to call this function in onBindView of recyclerView Adapter ?

Comment: If you have numerous number, are you sure it will not fit in a 1MiB? If yes, you'll save many read operations.

Comment: @ZarEAhmer Hello there, did you get any answers of that I am new in android so I could not find the answer of this I was thinking the same way is there any solution?